# Hacer que todo el cuerpo de la página sea un enlace

Tags: html, web

Necesito que el al clickar en cualquier punto de la página web, se redirija al usuario a otra url.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: basta con `<body onclick="metodoEnviarAver()" ... >` y en una etiqueta `<script> function metodoEnviarAver(){ ... }</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con una función javascript que detecte cuando haces click al body:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(){
  window.location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Usar JQuery para manejar un simple evento como un click me parece demasiado

Answer (score 1):

solo debes crear una etiqueta `a` y este te llevara donde quieras

```css
span{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/webhp?client=firefox-b-d"><span>Click donde quieras</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Para que te descargas jquery si para ese ejemplo no te hace falta?